# Looking for a word for a group of words

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that refers to a group of five words where the only difference in spelling is the vowel?  And that all five vowels (in different words) are in the group?

Slang/jargon would probably not be included.

Example:

pat pet pit pot put

Comment: I don't know whether such a word exists. But _minimal pairs_ is the term for two words that differ in only one phonological element, such as _put/pet_, _sit/sat_, etc: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair. So you could coin the term _minimal quintuplets_.

Comment: I like this as well, as it can identify partial matches (i.e. minimal quadruples and the elusive minimal sextuplet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call this group a '***vowel alternation series***' by analogy with the 'gradation series' (ablaut).

As the sources of the particular pronunciation are different, we can't use the terms 'ablaut, umlaut, assimilation' here.

***Alternation*** would be quite appropriate:

: the occurrence of different allomorphs or allophones
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alternation).